# How do I make a waterbed environment from a 5 gallon bucket?

Tags: watering, containers

I'm wanting to grow some water plants like Watercress, and Ashitaba, but have nowhere to grow it at. How can I convert a 5 gallon bucket to grow a plant in each?

Answer (score 3):

I only know about the watercress, I filled a 10 inch pot  with drainage holes in the bottom about half way up with soil, I then put that pot into a larger pot about 11 ½  inch wide with no drainage holes then filled water up to the soil line or a bit more and planted seeds on top of the soil after completing drenching the soil first.

The watercress sprouted 6 days later and is growing like a forest, the roots will be completely happy if you keep the water level so it reaches the soil and change it to fresh a few times a month, any combination will work with whatever you want to do with it, I keep mine under grow lights and I will take it outside for the sun in the good weather and back in for winter.